# Canada Transit Visa Online application - Where is it processed and how long will it take?

Tags: air-travel, canada, transit-visas

I am a citizen from Philippines and currently residing in Bahamas. I am applying for a transit visa in Canada (22 days left) through online application. My questions are:
1) the online application does not indicate where my application is processed. Where is this processed?
2) do I need to send over my passport stamped/stick the visa?
3) how long does this take?

Appreciate your help!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Visa applications from the Bahamas are processed through the [visa office in Kingston, Jamaica](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/missions/kingston.asp).

As part of the process of applying for the visa, you will be requested to send your passport and any supporting documentation to the [Visa Application Centre in Kingston, Jamaica](http://www.csc-cvac.com/en-JM/selfservice/cvac_welcome). You can mail the documents or deliver them in person, but if you [need to give biometrics](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/biometrics.asp) (Philippine citizens do not) then you cannot mail your documents; you must deliver them in person.

After you have submitted your documents, you can check the status of your application in the Application Tracker. Note that the Kingston office currently shows a [processing time](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/temp/visitors.asp) of 34 days.

Comment: 34 days for a *transit* visa ? o.O

Comment: So even though I applied online? They still need the physical documents sent via mail? I read somewhere that it's easier to apply online to save cost of mailing the documents.

Comment: @blackbird57 the website includes other types (it says "temporary resident", which seems to be a category of visa rather than a specific type), so transit visa processing could be faster (or slower!) than the category average