# Canada Transit Visa approved - how long until my passport comes back?

Tags: canada, transit-visas, bahamian-citizens

I just receive confirmation that our visa is now approved. They need us to provide the passport. I am from Bahamas and we are required to send our passport to Jamaica (Kingston).

I need to fly out on 27 December 2015. How long do you think our passport would come back to us?

Comment: They are only going to put the visa in it, so _not long_.

Comment: You usually would have mailed it with a prepaid return shipping to your address, if that's the case then check with the courier company

Comment: How long did the visa take to get there in the end?

Answer (score 2):

> How long do you think our passport would come back to us?

As I have mentioned elsewhere [eg](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78693/4995), it seems visa processing times depend to some extent on the time available. Since you required yours by Dec 27 and in view of Christmas, I believe you could reasonably have expected to receive it on or by Dec 24, if passport sent by you on Dec 14 by reasonably fast means. This however is not to say that 10 days is standard or recommended for Bahamas to Jamaica and back.

So I think *about 10 days*.

Based on your last recorded visit here, there is some reason to supposed that it may have taken 9 days (ie that you stopped looking here for an answer once you passport arrived back).

---

Did not know when I wrote the above but [Note that the Kingston office currently shows a processing time of 34 days.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/59523/4995) and the link sourcing that *at present* indicates 45 days for the closest category match I could find (Visitor visa - from outside Canada) and *Does not include transit time between the VAC and IRCC office.* and other provisos that wait could be longer still.